# Why images are aligned to the bottom of a div?

Tags: html, layout, alignment

In the following example, the image is aligned to the bottom of the parent container:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
  <div>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img{
    height: 2em;
    top: 0px;
}

div div {
    width: 5em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Can use this JSFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/9nLyr6f6/2/

1. I was just curious to know what the logic is for that? What rule applies?
2. How to change it and have the image at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

To change it, set the vertical-align property on the image to something other than its default.

```css
img{
    height: 2em;
    top: 0px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

div div {
    width: 5em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
  <div>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image and the inner div are both `inline-block` elements, which are aligned on the baseline of the text. So the outer div actually contains one line of 'text'. This line doesn't contain actual text, but only two blocks: the image and the inner div. Both are aligned on the base line.

You can see this especially if you add some text and a border. The image aligns with the base line of the text.

```css
img{
    height: 2em;
    top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
div div {
    width: 5em;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  A
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
  B
  <div>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</div>
  Cxyz
</div>
```

You can solve this by adding `vertical-align: top` to the image:

```css
img{
    height: 2em;
    top: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div div {
    width: 5em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
  <div>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</div>
</div>
```